# Not able to click on the Add button

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, protractor

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root jss48321 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 MuiGrid-grid-sm-3 MuiGrid-grid-md-3 MuiGrid-grid-lg-3 MuiGrid-grid-xl-3">
<h4 class="MuiTypography-root jss48324 MuiTypography-h4">Decks</h4>
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiFab-root jss48323 MuiFab-sizeSmall MuiFab-primary" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="add" title="Add">
<span class="MuiFab-label">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
</svg>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button></div>
```

Since it is react js application, I added

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Here I wanted to click on the add icon (+)

My test script:

```
describe('IEC', function () {
it('Login', function () {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.get('cannot provide the url since it requires VPN');
element(by.css('input[type="text"]')).sendKeys('12345');
element(by.css('input[type="password"]')).sendKeys('Pwd');
element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
element(by.css('button[title="Add"]')).click();
});
});
```

Output:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, button[title="Add"])

How can I resolve this issue?#

Comment: did you add explicit wait

Comment: I agree with the above comment, you will need to create your own explicit wait. So something like a browser.wait for the element being in the DOM (i think that is isPresent)

Comment: you need to provide the full code snippet and not only the line where YOU think it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @SergeyPleshakov Added the complete code now. Please check.

Comment: Hi @PDHide, i tried with the explicit  wait, it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor has built in waiting specific to Angular pages. Your page is react, and by running `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` you disable that waiting

Now your code just does what you instruct it to: set username and password and click submit. Probably 5 milliseconds later you attempt to click add button? but it's not present. I'm pretty sure it's will take at least 10 seconds to load the application after logging in. So you need to add that step. Either `browser.sleep(15000)` which is VERY bad practice, of add explicit wait for a condition using `browser.wait`

Also, each line of your code returns Promise, but you don't handle it. The side effect is the order of your commands is not guaranteed. I already told you this in previous posts you need to use `async/await`. Unless you do so, you'll be having thousands of problems, I guarantee

Comment: Hi @ Sergey Pleshakov, got the better understanding now. i might miss your comments in previous post. Any ways thanks for clarification.